# What's the name of the music in One Piece filler episode 406?

Tags: one-piece, music

In One Piece's episode 406. Whats the name of the music that starts playing on the 2:30 mark after the opening?

Comment: Could you give a link to the music? There does not seem to be any music at the 2:30 mark?

Answer (score 1):

This song is called Master Usopp from Baron Omatsuri and The Secret Island OST.

Episode link:[Episode 406](http://www.crunchyroll.com/one-piece/episode-406-feudal-era-side-story-boss-luffy-appears-again-658643)

Music link:[Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_tqDMPQY-o)

Comment: I have removed the link to the illegal steam site. in futrure please refer to [this list](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/1587) for legal sites to link to